# SQL Monthly Summary

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that contains a startdate for each item

for example:

```
ID - Startdate
1  - 2011-01-01
2  - 2011-02-01
3  - 2011-04-01
...
```

I need a query that will give me the count of each item within each month, i need a full 12 month report. I tried simply grouping by the `Month(StartDate)` but this doesnt give me a zero for the months with no values, in the case above, for march.

so i would like the output to be along the lines of..

```
Month - Count
  1      20
  2      14
  3      0
...
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Whic server you are using? Sql Server, MySql, Oracle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT A.Month, ISNULL(B.countvalue,0) Count
FROM (SELECT 1 AS MONTH
UNION 
SELECT 2 
UNION 
SELECT 3 
UNION 
SELECT 4 
UNION 
SELECT 5 
UNION 
SELECT 6 
UNION 
SELECT 7 
UNION 
SELECT 8 
UNION 
SELECT 9 
UNION 
SELECT 10 
UNION 
SELECT 11 
UNION 
SELECT 12 ) A LEFT JOIN (SELECT datepart(month,Startdate) AS Month, Count(ID) as countvalue FROM yourTable GROUP BY datepart(month,Startdate))B
ON A.month = B.month
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Worked great, i realise some of the other answers would work, but i was after something simple, thanks to everyone.

Comment: i used `Month(StartDate)` rather than `datepart(month, StartDate)` not sure if it would make much difference?

Answer (score 5):

Another way to do this using `SQL Server 2005+` or `Oracle`.

#### SQL Statement

```
;WITH q (Month) AS (
    SELECT  1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  Month + 1
    FROM    q   
    WHERE   q.Month < 12
)
SELECT  q.Month
        , COUNT(i.ID)
FROM    q
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Input i ON MONTH(i.StartDate) = q.Month
GROUP BY
        q.Month
```

#### Test script

```
;WITH Input (ID, StartDate) AS (
    SELECT 1, '2011-01-01'
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, '2011-02-01'
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, '2011-04-01'
)
, q (Month) AS (
    SELECT  1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  Month + 1
    FROM    q   
    WHERE   q.Month < 12
)
SELECT  q.Month
        , COUNT(i.ID)
FROM    q
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Input i ON MONTH(i.StartDate) = q.Month
GROUP BY
        q.Month
```

Comment: Beautiful ! Recursive CTEs ... this is a good cue for many DB analysts out there

Comment: @Baaju - it's allways a tradeoff. They tend to shorten the statement but do not necesarily improve readability or performance. In this case, it doesn't hurt.

Comment: Agreed, but assume the case where i need to generate this for a 50 years with 12 months each ! Now then the recusrsive CTE comes in handy to build the base from which i can go on !